# How to simplify expression with Fermat's little theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image: Fermat's little theorem]

I don't quite understand how to reduce

$(25^{74} + 53^{27})^{10}$

I thought I would reduce to $(4^{74} + 4^{27})^{10}$ and then $(4^{7*10 + 4} + 4^ {7*3 + 6})^{7*1 + 3}$

And then $(4^4 + 4^6)^3$ but that doesn't seem like what the answer got so how does one simplify the expression using Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: $a^{6k+r}\equiv a^r\pmod 7$

Comment: Ahh, honest mistake. Thank you!